# Can't retrieve access_token, refresh_token from Omniauth authentication strategy with Devise, Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

I am using such gems:

```
gem "omniauth-yandex"
gem 'devise'
```

My setup.

**Routes**:

```
 devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "callbacks" }
```

**Devise initializer**:

```
config.omniauth :yandex, Rails.application.secrets.client_id , Rails.application.secrets.password, callback_url: "http://cb2bcdc4.ngrok.io/users/auth/yandex/callback"
```

**User model**:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:yandex]


   def self.from_omniauth(auth) 

      where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
        user.provider = auth.provider
        user.uid = auth.uid
        user.email =  auth.info.email
        user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      end

  end
```

**CallbackController**:

```
class CallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController        

    def yandex
       #empty
    end
end
```

**View:**

```
  <%= link_to "Sign in with Yandex", user_yandex_omniauth_authorize_path, id: "sign_in" %>
```

When I click "Sign in with Yandex" my application prompts for user permission and then redirects back to my application. User is created in my database with such fields-- e-mail,provider, uid. But I would like to have also access_token, refresh_token and expires_at because I am using few Yandex API's.

When I httlog'ed above action (From clicking "Sign in .." to the redirect back to my application) I received these results:

```
D, [2017-04-26T19:17:42.091838 #24865] DEBUG -- : [0;30;101m[httplog] Connecting: oauth.yandex.ru:443[0m
D, [2017-04-26T19:17:42.266645 #24865] DEBUG -- : [0;30;101m[httplog] Sending: POST http://oauth.yandex.ru:443/token[0m
D, [2017-04-26T19:17:42.267040 #24865] DEBUG -- : [0;30;101m[httplog] Data: client_id=097253682f9f41289ec5exxxxxxx&client_secret=xxxxxxdb4fxx0eadcbb8a4143&code=xxxxx327&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fcb2bcdc4.ngrok.io%2Fusers%2Fauth%2Fyandex%2Fcallback%3Fstate%xxxxxxxxxxx%26code%xxxx[0m
D, [2017-04-26T19:17:42.410712 #24865] DEBUG -- : [0;30;101m[httplog] Status: 200[0m
D, [2017-04-26T19:17:42.410945 #24865] DEBUG -- : [0;30;101m[httplog] Benchmark: 0.143445 seconds[0m
D, [2017-04-26T19:17:42.411168 #24865] DEBUG -- : [0;30;101m[httplog] Response:
{"token_type": "bearer", "access_token": "xxxxxxxxuyBwtcyAFjkBZo3F3MCiIaTI", "expires_in": 31528753, "refresh_token": "xxxxxxxxxxxClSH:Pts0u-Mfls-vdEc7-zTOod9ZWzegNFRxxxxxxxxxxxxxKHpwsqBFUHHKtg"}[0m
D, [2017-04-26T19:17:42.414748 #24865] DEBUG -- : [0;30;101m[httplog] Connecting: login.yandex.ru:443[0m
D, [2017-04-26T19:17:42.609376 #24865] DEBUG -- : [0;30;101m[httplog] Sending: GET http://login.yandex.ru:443/info?format=json[0m
D, [2017-04-26T19:17:42.609720 #24865] DEBUG -- : [0;30;101m[httplog] Data: [0m
D, [2017-04-26T19:17:42.675702 #24865] DEBUG -- : [0;30;101m[httplog] Status: 200[0m
D, [2017-04-26T19:17:42.675972 #24865] DEBUG -- : [0;30;101m[httplog] Benchmark: 0.065791 seconds[0m
D, [2017-04-26T19:17:42.676211 #24865] DEBUG -- : [0;30;101m[httplog] Response:
{"first_name": "xxxxxxxxxxx9", "last_name": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "display_name": "xxxxx", "emails": ["xxxxxx@yandex.ru"], "default_email": "xxxxx@yandex.ru", "real_name": "xxxxxx2", "login": "xxxxxxx", "sex": "male", "id": "xxxx123"}[0m
```

**Question**: How can I save access_token, refresh token from Omniauth authentication process to user as it is clearly visible (7th line ) that it does retrieve it using my client_id and secret without any of my code.

Thanks.

**What I have tried:**

Added `user.access_token = auth.credentials.token` to `self.from_omniauth(auth)` method in user model. But there wasn't any positive change.

**UPDATE**:

The same problem exists on different platforms. For example, on shared hosting and in Linux Ubuntu (completely fresh project from scratch).

Comment: Have you tried to debug params in the `yandex` action of `CallbackController`? something like `puts params` ? I'm pretty sure the access_token returned in the `params` not in the `auth` hash.

Comment: @Зелёный , Yes, I tried. I am only getting  'state' and 'code' params.

Comment: please share what you get by `p response.headers.fetch('Access-Token')` or `p response.headers.fetch('access_token')` or just `p response.headers`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The access token is provided by the yandex gem, or to be more specific, the [`omniauth-oauth2`](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-oauth2/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth2.rb) gem.

Just get inside your controller by doing: `request.env["omniauth.auth"].credentials.token`

Boom. That's your access token. (refresh token and expiry data is also in the `credentials` hash, just print it out)

Comment: How do you refresh the token if its just a string?  For example the Oauth gem has this refresh method:
https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth-oauth2/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth2.rb#L92C31-L92C43